# The meaning of "On" in this phrasal verbs

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have a sentence:

> But when I pushed on the door, it swung open, and so we went on inside.

I'm interested in the meaning of "on". I found explanations about what **on** can mean, and one of the explanations is that we use **on** when the direction of the act goes **inside**.

That is, we push **on** the door means we push it from ourselves, right?

It's easy for understanding if it is so. But the phrase **we went on inside**.... Why we need **on** there? *We went inside* and *we went on inside* are absolutely the same for me.

Comment: Look for the phrasal verb 'go on'.

Comment: _Push on the door_ means _apply pressure to the door_.

Comment: @KateBunting why not "push the door"? Why do we need ON here?

Comment: We could say _push the door_, but _push_ usually means that the thing being pushed is intended to move forward (a vehicle or person). Here, the speaker apparently 'pushed on the door' to see what would happen, and discovered that it wasn't locked and therefore swung open.

Comment: @KateBunting ohh. Thank you but it's still difficult) as I understood "push on" can mean "check if it's locked"

Comment: No, you can't say that it 'means' that. All the sentence says is that the speaker applied pressure to the door and found that it opened easily. You don't say where the sentence comes from, so I'm only guessing that he didn't necessarily expect the door to open.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you so much. Maybe next time I come across something similar I'll be able to spot it

Answer (score 1):

Here, *and so we went on inside*, on is used in a grammatically correct way.
The reason **on** is used here is because it’s part of *we went on*. To go on is to continue, and here it’s used in 1st person plural.
So, the reason why it’s used here is because they’re saying that *they **continued** on* inside.

Comment: they continued what?

Comment: @Bari I’m guessing they ‘continued’ going inside/ going wherever they were. I’m not sure since there’s not enough context.

Comment: thanks for explanation)